# first time training data and I found problem with "train" in linear regression model

Tags: python

I really don't understand why. I mean is `train` from sklearn or numpy?

That's part of the code I imported pandas,numpy,sklearn,matplotlib, and pylab

```
train_x =np.asanyarray(train[['X']])
```

message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c7eab19d3b2c> in <module>
      1 from sklearn import linear_model
      2 regr=linear_model.LinearRegression()
----> 3 train_x =np.asanyarray(train[['X']])
      4 train_y =np.asanyarray(train[['Y']])
      5 regr.fit(train_x,train_y)

NameError: name 'train' is not defined
```

Comment: You don't seem to have defined any variable `train`; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` (tags edited).

Answer (score 0):

`train` is a variable that your code attempts to use as an array, while, as your error points out, it's not defined. This is a mistake in handling variables in general. The solution to this issue is to properly initialize `train` before you use it and do the same with other variables as well.